# Show that $\frac{1}{x+y}$ is a valid kernel

Tags: inner-products

Problem $5.2(c)$ in Foundations of Machine Learning (Mohri et al. 2012)

Show that $\kappa(x,y)=\frac{1}{x+y}$ is a valid PSD kernel over $(0, \infty) \times(0,\infty) $.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the range of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention them, yes, it's given that x,y are strictly positive. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\kappa(x,y)=\int_0^\infty \exp(-tx)\exp(-ty)dt$, so $$\sum_{i,j} a_ia_j \kappa(x_i,x_j) = \int_0^\infty \left|\sum_i a_i\exp(-tx_i)\right|^2dt \ge0.$$

This gives you PSD, but you can also verify strict positive definiteness by noting that for no finite combination of $i_i$ is the sum $\sum_i a_i\exp(-tx_i)$ the zero function.